# Javascript and JQUERY: opening and closing divs using click function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building an online interactive map for Taiwan census data and I have a javascript question.

The map takes the full width and height of the page but when two divs are clicked (click_1956 and click_1966) two containers open on the right side of the page and the width of the map shrinks accordingly.

In these containers graphs are shown. Each container has a div inside that hosts the graphs.

Everything works, but if I click click_1956 and chart_container_1956 opens, and then click click_1966 and chart_container_1966 opens, when I click click_1966 again to close the chart_container_1966, then chart_container_1956 is still open. I would like all the containers to close when any of them is closed.

I hope this makes sense. I pasted the code below. I apologize if it doesn't make sense. This is my first time using this website. Thank you!

**CSS**

```
#charts_container_1956 {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        width:0;
        height:100%;
        z-index:10;
        background:#FAFAFF; 
        display:none;
    }
#chart_1956 {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    top:0;
    width:78%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    left:21%;
    z-index:1000;
    background:#B6CEFF; 
    display: none;
}

#click_1956{
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    opacity:0.85;
    background-image:url("images/chart.png");
    background-size:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-bottom:6px;
}

#click_1956:hover {
    background-color: #B6CEFF;
}

#charts_container_1966 {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:0;
    height:100%;
    z-index:10;
    background:#FAFAFF; 
    display:none;
}

#chart_1966 {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    top:0;
    width:78%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    left:21%;
    z-index:1000;
    background:#B6CEFF; 
    display: none;
}

#click_1966{
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    opacity:0.85;
    background-image:url("images/chart.png");
    background-size:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-bottom:6px;
}

#click_1966:hover {
    background-color: #B6CEFF;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('#click_1956').click(function() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  if (clicks) {
  $("#map").animate({
    width: "100%"
  }, 300 );
    $('#charts_container_1956').animate({
        width: "0"
    },300);
    $("#chart_1956").fadeToggle(100);
  } else {
   $("#map").animate({
    width: "20.5%"
  }, 300 );
    $('#charts_container_1956').animate({
        width: "79.5%"
    },300);
    $("#chart_1956").fadeToggle(1000)
  }   
    $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
   });
  });

  $(function () {
  var categories = ['0-4', '5-9', '10-14', '15-19',
        '20-24', '25-29', '30-34', '35-39', '40-44',
        '45-49', '50-54', '55-59', '60-64', '65-69',
        '70-74', '75-79', '80-84', '85-89', '90-94',
        '95-99', '100 + '];
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#chart_container_1956').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: '人口金字塔'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: '1956年'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: [{
            categories: categories,
            reversed: false,
            labels: {
                step: 1
            }
        }, { // mirror axis on right side
            opposite: true,
            reversed: false,
            categories: categories,
            linkedTo: 0,
            labels: {
                step: 1
            }
        }],
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return (Math.abs(this.value) / 1000000) + 'M';
                }
            },
            min: -2000000,
            max: 2000000
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + ', age ' + this.point.category + '</b><br>' +
                    'Population: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.abs(this.point.y), 0);
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: '男',
            data: [-930097, -708733, -478299, -487623, -336419, -362280, -325520, -281719, -251974, -205500, -153693, -109738, -71686, -47206, -45708, -0, -0, -0, -0, -0, -0]
        }, {
            name: '女',
            data: [886484,  670598, 448470, 463230, 403966, 356909, 297371, 240970, 203159, 173283, 133860, 105011, 74621,  57448,  78806, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        }]
    });
});
```

});

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('#click_1966').click(function() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  if (clicks) {
  $("#map").animate({
    width: "100%"
  }, 300 );
    $('#charts_container_1966').animate({
        width: "0"
    },300);
    $("#chart_1966").fadeToggle(100);
  } else {
   $("#map").animate({
    width: "20.5%"
  }, 300 );
    $('#charts_container_1966').animate({
        width: "79.5%"
    },300);
    $("#chart_1966").fadeToggle(1000) 
}   
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
```

});

```
$(function () {
var categories = ['0-4', '5-9', '10-14', '15-19',
        '20-24', '25-29', '30-34', '35-39', '40-44',
        '45-49', '50-54', '55-59', '60-64', '65-69',
        '70-74', '75-79', '80-84', '85-89', '90-94',
        '95-99', '100 + '];
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#chart_container_1966').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: '人口金字塔'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: '1966年'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: [{
            categories: categories,
            reversed: false,
            labels: {
                step: 1
            }
        }, { // mirror axis on right side
            opposite: true,
            reversed: false,
            categories: categories,
            linkedTo: 0,
            labels: {
                step: 1
            }
        }],
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return (Math.abs(this.value) / 1000000) + 'M';
                }
            },
            min: -2000000,
            max: 2000000
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + ', age ' + this.point.category + '</b><br>' +
                    'Population: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.abs(this.point.y), 0);
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: '男',
            data: [-1018498, -996308, -919856, -682964, -324702, -461254, -430342, -436479, -377743, -306094, -261970, -185797, -127501, -79309, -43250, -20839, -11100, -0, -0, -0, -0]
        }, {
            name: '女',
            data: [959981, 943937, 872920,  671050, 446428, 458478, 399311, 354333, 293547, 234241, 195507, 161451, 119448, 86079, 54002, 32911, 25133, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        }]
    });
});
```

});

Comment: Your first codebox (starting with the css) seem to contain content of the other two boxes.

Could you also add the HTML?

You might want to show us what you currently got using the Runnable Code Snippets: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Where can I edit my question to include a link to the Runnable Code Snippets with my code?

Comment: try https://jsfiddle.net/ ,there you can post your code and share the link

Comment: No need for JSFiddle, you can do the exact same right here in StackOverflow. Read the link (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). "How Do I Make A Stack Snippet?" describes exactly how...

Answer (score 0):

When opening one div, look for opened divs and close these. This way only one div at a time will be opened.

When you close an opened div there won't be any other opened div anymore ;)

Here is some pseudo code:

```js
jQuery().ready(function()
{
  $('.openable').click(function()
  {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('opened'))
    {
      $(this).animate({ width: '90%', height: '100%' }, 500).addClass('opened').siblings('.openable.opened').animate({ width: '10%', height: '100px' }).removeClass('opened')
    }
    else
    {
      $(this).animate({ width: '10%', height: '100px' }).removeClass('opened');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html, body, #container { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
.openable { position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; width: 10%; height: 100px; background-color: #00f; }
.openable:first-child { left: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="openable" id="one"></div>
  <div class="openable" id="two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have not been able to write that if statement in my javascript and get it to work..

Comment: I am trying to integrate that in my own code now and having some difficulties. I try to use Runnable Code Snippets but my code links to lot of geojson files hosted on mycomputer that I can not seem to include.

Answer (score 0):

What i can suggest is instead of using `slidetoggle`,use `show` and `hide` which will make your job easier.
While closing 1956 tab what am doing is ,Am selecting all the div's which starts with an id `chart_19` and closing all of them.
You can use the same piece of code in all the click functions to make it work.

```
 $('#click_1956').click(function() {..................});
$('#click_1955').click(function() {..................});
```

> Code changes

```
$('#click_1956').click(function() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  if (clicks) {
  $("#map").animate({
    width: "100%"
  }, 300 );
    $('#charts_container_1956').animate({
        width: "0"
    },300);
    $("#chart_1956").show(100);
  } else {
   $("#map").animate({
    width: "20.5%"
  }, 300 );
    $('#charts_container_1956').animate({
        width: "79.5%"
    },300);
    $('div[id^="chart_19"]').hide(1000)
  }   
    $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
   });
  });
```

Comment: That works. But if both my charts have been opened once and I want to go back to the first chart by clicking again to show it, instead of showing it, it will close the all divs.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ 
 $('#click_1956').click(function() {
   var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
   if (clicks) {
   $("#map").animate({
  width: "100%"
   }, 300 );
  $('#charts_container_1956').animate({
   width: "0"
  },300);
  $("#chart_1956").hide(100);
  $('div[id^="chart_19"]').hide(100)
   } else {
    $("#map").animate({
  width: "20.5%"
   }, 300 );
  $('#charts_container_1956').animate({
   width: "79.5%"
  },300);
  $("#chart_1956").show(300)
 }   
   $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
 });
});